# does robotium support double touch?

Tags: android, robotium

Does "ROBOTIUM " support 2 finger touch? Actually i want to write a testcase in which the user taps and hold one button and clicks on another button using other finger.
is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

Actually, it's not supported. You can write enhancement here:
http://code.google.com/p/robotium/issues/list

Answer (score 0):

It is possible, its not easy but its possible. You will need to [MotionEvent](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MotionEvent.html) which you can dispatch as per your need.